# Excluding jQuery from Chrome Dev Tools backtrace

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, backtrace

Is there a way to exclude jQuery, AngularJS and other libraries from the call stack (backtrace) when an exception occurs?

The problem is that if a function throws an exception somewhere in my code, I can't see from where exactly it became, because the stack shows just calls inside jQuery's functions.

Comment: Or a way to have it show more than the default ~10 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that starting from Chrome 37 or maybe 38 you can exclude the scripts from the debugger (not from the backtrace thou). It's a feature called `Blackbox script`. You can read more about it here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing